# ajp_msg_append_cvt_string(): BufferOverflowException on apache 2.4

Tags: apache, tomcat8

In below code from apache server ajp_msg.c, any idea where the
msg->max_size is coming from ?

I am trying to fix error message below :

ajp_msg_append_cvt_string(): BufferOverflowException 4 8186

```
**
*  Add a String in AJP message, and transform the String in ASCII
*  if convert is set and we're on an EBCDIC machine
*
* @param msg       AJP Message to get value from
* @param value     Pointer to String
* @param convert   When set told to convert String to ASCII
* @return          APR_SUCCESS or error
*/
apr_status_t ajp_msg_append_string_ex(ajp_msg_t *msg, const char *value,
                                      int convert)
{
    apr_size_t len;

    if (value == NULL) {
        return(ajp_msg_append_uint16(msg, 0xFFFF));
    }

    len = strlen(value);
    if ((msg->len + len + 3) > msg->max_size) {
        return ajp_log_overflow(msg, "ajp_msg_append_cvt_string");
    }

    /* ignore error - we checked once */
    ajp_msg_append_uint16(msg, (apr_uint16_t)len);

    /* We checked for space !!  */
    memcpy(msg->buf + msg->len, value, len + 1); /* including \0 */

    if (convert) {
        /* convert from EBCDIC if needed */
        ap_xlate_proto_to_ascii((char *)msg->buf + msg->len, len + 1);
    }

    msg->len += len + 1;

    return APR_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needed ProxyIOBufferSize in apache config and packetSize in tomcat config on AJP connection. The apache config number must be less than or equal to tomcat packetSize. safest is to make them equal.

both of them were set to 64 kb i.e. 65,536 max allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `max_packet_size` attribute. The default value in AJP is **8192**.

This attribute sets the maximal AJP packet size in Bytes. The maximum value you can set is **65536**. If you change it from the default, you must also change the `packetSize` attribute of your AJP connector on the Tomcat side! The attribute `packetSize` is available in Tomcat 6.0.2 onwards.
The above settings needs to be done in the tomcat-connector and tomcat itself (a corresponding setting must be made in the AJP  element in Tomcat's conf/server.xml file).

See [here](https://www.techpaste.com/2016/12/413-request-entity-large/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was this

```
AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release /home/jadmin_q/apache2/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:1
```

As mentioned i opened the file httpd-vhosts.conf and line number 1 and commented the line NameVirtualHost and next time the error did not came